# Embedding an angular 1.3 app in a Angular 2 app

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am trying to build and app using Angular 2 which has several tabs. I want one of these tabs to be as the already created angular 1.3.17 app. More specifically, I want to embed [Netflix Vector](https://github.com/koustubh25/millvi-dashboard-app.git) into one of my tabs. My Angular 2 app is uploaded here (at the moment does nothing) [here](https://github.com/koustubh25/millvi-dashboard-app.git). Would this be possible?
I don't intend to have any interaction between the Angular 2 components and Angular 1.x. I simply want to embed it.

I also tried the following:

The way to run [Netflix Vector](https://github.com/Netflix/vector.git) is simply doing a gulp build and then running a simple server inside the `dist` directory.

So, to ease the way of embedding such a large application, I tried to put the dist directory inside my angular 2 component directory and then just modifying the index.html to remove the inclusion of scripts and css. I loaded those scripts and css through my main index.html.

Then I loaded `index.html` through my angular 2 component. I have made sure that the angular libraries and all other `js` files  are loaded. However, it doesnt seem to work just by providing a `ng-app` directive inside `index.html`

Comment: it is possible and doesn't matter whether you want to use Angular2 components within your 1.3 app or use Angular 2 "App" within it.

Comment: Will it be possible to give a sample code to show how to do the same?